# How do I drop/ignore characters past a certain number in getline?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying out dynamic memory allocation. I want to dynamically allocate memory, enough for a string of 10 characters. If the user inputs more than 10, I only want 10 characters pulled in getline (plus the newline character, I suppose) and subsequently stored in correct size dynamic memory, printed, and deleted. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char cont = 'N';

do{
    char *input = new char[11];
    cout << "This program dynamically allocates memory for a string of 
    characters up to 10 in length\n";
    cout << "Enter a string less than or equal to 10 characters:\n";
    cin.getline(input, 11, '\n');

    cout << "Your string is:\n";
    cout << input << endl << endl;
    delete input;

    cout << "Would you like to enter another? \"Y\" to continue\n";
    cin >> cont;
    cin.ignore();

} while (toupper(cont) == 'Y');
```

Everything works fine if the user inputs up to 10 characters. It can repeat forever.

However if the user inputs more than 10 characters the program does not prompt the user to continue and instead just ends. ABCDEFGHIJ works but ABCDEFGHIJK breaks.

I thought this is because there is still something in cin that is being read in to input, which is not 'Y' and the program therefore ends. However if you go through one loop and set cont to 'Y' first, and then input ABCDEFGHIJK, the program goes infinite without ever inputting anything to overwrite 'Y'.

Another thing I noticed is getline seems to pull the correct amount of characters it stores characters ABCDEFGHIJ in input, even if ABCDEFGHIJK was entered.I thought perhaps 'K' was left in cin, so I tried ABCDEFGHIJY but 'Y' was not saved in to cont.

I also tried various cin.clear() variations before the next prompt for input, and nothing worked.

I think I am misunderstanding how getline works with the overload I am using.

Comment: To put it simply, don't write code like this - use a std::string.  Apart from anything else, your new[] and delete don't match up.

Comment: You cannot use `std::istream::getline` for this, because you have no indication whether the `getline` member function consumed the newline, or stopped because the maximum character count was reached. This information gets lost. You should use `std::string` and the standalone `std::getline`() function, and you want to truncate the read string do it yourself, using `substr`().

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell you, that doing this with a string is a ton easier, but if you want to do it the hard, allocating way...

---

#### Problem:

When you read with `std::cin`, and some condition isn't met, for example, reading a string as an int, or running out of specified characters, the failbit is set. This makes your istream look crazy

#### Fix:

Put a check after the getline call, test if the fail bit is set, if it is, reset the flags.

```cpp
/* ... */

cin.getline(input, 11, '\n'); // Read input

if ( cin.fail() ) { // Check if getline failed
    // -- > Remind the user of the limits here < --

    // Clear flags
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}

/* ... */
```

---

Your `getline` variation has the arguments: `char_type * Output, std::streampos MaxLength, char_type Delimeter`. Sets failbit if the number of bytes to read is greater than the maximum length *(AFAIK)*.

#### Sources:

- [std::basic_istream::fail()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail)
- [std::basic_istream::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Wish luck with your dynamic allocations, COlda